# Is there anyway to send mock barcodes from appium mobile automation to testing apk?

Tags: android, appium, ui-automation, appium-android

I need to send mock barcodes to my testing apk from appium test automation suit.

What I'm trying to do is to parse a string(barcode) as a parameter to a method(in my automation script) which convert that string to a barcode and inject it into the application. (While my automation script is running).

Is there anyway to convert string to barcode from automation suit and send them while automation is running?

I have tried to search about this and I find some solutions like some applications which can send simulated barcodes, but I need to send converted strings as barcodes through my automation script.

I'm using java 8

Appium version : 1.6.2

Android version :8.1

Comment: according to my appilcation , it is a price checker, so I need to scan them while in automation. Those are the scenarios we have to automate

Comment: I need to mock barcodes to my test automation. When I do it in Windows I used mqtt, but in here it doesn't work